# VB.NET NotifyIcon BalloonTipText Not Displaying

Tags: vb.net

I can get the notifyicon to display in the system tray but for some reason, any balloon messages do not show. I am running on Windows 10 - if that makes a difference.

The code I am using is

```
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        Me.Hide()
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Double click to launch app"
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you set the icon?  Show a more complete example.

Comment: on form load i am using NotifyIcon1.Icon = Me.Icon

Comment: Set a `new Icon(...)` (see the constructors, pick what's best in that context).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).